# Etymology of "wildcard"

Tags: etymology

I was wondering where "wildcard" in computing terms comes from ?

*Note: Did not find it in etymonline.com and don't know of any similar resources to consult.*

Comment: A non-computing sense has been asked about here: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/93685/what-is-the-origin-for-meaning-of-wild-card/

Comment: and that one is the same meaning.

Comment: Agreed, saw this after my answer, but this is a duplicate.

Comment: And here's the [etymonline.com entry](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=wild+card&allowed_in_frame=0) (with a space).

Comment: I'm sorry...for not being able to vote up anyone due to reputation as well as..I don't know. I still would not have been satisfied with "wild card" (the space) but my apologies anyway. And thanks for the wonderful insights (see meaning of "wild")!

Comment: Well, *wildcard* without a space is a closed compound, formed because *wild card* with a space was so often used. It does mean the same thing, and etymologically *wildcard < wild card*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In some card games, you can have a *wild* card that the holder can play with any value of their choosing.

Hence, if deuces were wild, you could have three-of-a-kind with a deuce and two kings, by counting the wild 2 as another king.

The computing sense of characters that match any character is by analogy to that.

Comment: thanks but why was it called "wild" and not e.g., joker card or bonus card or strike card or win card or the like?

Comment: What do you call a person that doesn't behave by the normal rules, or an animal that isn't domesticated and hence follows no rules? *Wild*

Comment: ah! thanks :) .oO(weird, this sounds a bit like me ;)) kidding ;)